# How to avoid 404 error when case insensitive using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a small doubt regarding htaccess.

My URL : http://example.com/shop

But when I try with http://example.com/SHOP it gives me 404 Not found error.

How to solve this using htaccess ?

i need SHOP and shop should be pointed to shop

Thanks

Comment: And where is your `.htaccess` file?! Ordinary one would flag the regex with `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, "shop" and "SHOP" simply are different things from a technical point of view. If you want to override that distinction you need to rewrite incoming requests.

This would be an example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop$
RewiteRule ^/?SHOP$ /shop [NC,QSA,END]
```

This would be a more flexible approach matching longer paths:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop
RewiteRule ^/?SHOP(.*)$ /shop$1 [NC,QSA,END]
```

This obviously requires the rewriting module being loaded and activated in your http server. You should implement such rule in the http server's host configuration, or, if you do not have access to that, in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess").